# programming light sources in java

Tags: 3d, java, software-engineering, mmo, lighting

I was making a game and I wanted to program light sources but I don't know how to. every where I search it comes up with lightweight java. Can any one offer any help. Its a birds eye view mmorpg. Can anyone help me?

Comment: dose any one even know where else i can look?

Comment: Either google `game development light sources`, or expand your question a bit more.  What sort of light sources do you want, what have you tried, what sort of math are you familiar with?

Comment: Java is a language, not a rendering engine.  Check out existing game engines like Monkey, LWJGL, and other rendering engine wrappers like JOGL and see how they handle lighting.  If you have questions after that then following up on their forums or here will net you much better answers than with an overly general question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, [this](http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl8.htm) may not be what exactly you are looking for. But, here you might find some guideline to sort it out.